# Why is the result of this short C program "3 2"?

Tags: c, enums

Here is the source code：

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    enum coordinate_type{ RECTANGULAR = 1,POLAR };

    int main(void)
    {
        int RECTANGULAR;
        printf("%d %d\n",RECTANGULAR,POLAR);
        return 0;
    }
```

Why is the result the following:

```
3 2
```

Comment: Because you declare an uninitialized variable `RECTANGULAR` which, by coincidence, contains the value `3` when you print it. It's undefined behaviour and could contain any value. You probably meant `int value = RECTANGULAR;` and then print `value` with `printf()`.

Comment: What do you think that `int RECTANGULAR; ` does?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Comment: You should compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then you'll get warnings, and you should improve your code till you get no warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are redefining what RECTANGULAR is in the main function. It gets initialized with a "random" value, in this case it is 3, but it could be anything else.

POLAR keps its value of 2 because of how the enum is defined.

Try redefining the RECTANGULAR variable in main to see different outputs.